# how to get Orders with its all products

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have question about order table design in MySQL.
I have ORDERS table like

```
Order_id | Customer_id | Total_Price | 
--------------------------------------
```

And on other side I have table PRODUCT

```
Product_id | Product_name | available_amount 
------------------------------------------
```

An order can contain several different Products.
So,how can I change or update my database design like that I can efficiently access any Order with its all Products?
Should I create seperate table names Order_details? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. You will want to create a separate table, like you mentioned, bringing together the Order and all of its Products, like so:

```
    Order_Product_id | Order_id | Product_id
    ----------------------------------------
    1                | 1        | 1
    2                | 1        | 3
    3                | 1        | 5
    4                | 2        | 3
    5                | 3        | 1
    6                | 3        | 2
```

Then you can get all the Products which are in an order like so:

```
Select op.Order_id, p.Product_id, p.Product_name 
FROM Product p 
JOIN Order_Product op ON op.Product_id = p.Product_id
WHERE op.Order_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you could see [this](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

you have an order which have multi products and product could be in one or many orders then you have many-to-many relationship.

you just need to add new table with this schema **order_products(id, order_id, product_id)**

- **id** to make the row unique
- **order_id** foreign key of any order you have
- **product_id** foreign key of any product but in here it will be related to this **order_id**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the relation between orders and products are many to many, so you must break this relation by doing third table called order_products or order_details, this table has order_id, product_id as foreign keys.
Also you should add quantity field, and sales_price field for this table.
Also you shouldn't put the total_price in orders table, but you can calculate the total by sum(quantity*sales_price) fields in the third table.